# Concatenating Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, key

I have three lists, the first is a list of names, the second is a list of dictionaries, and the third is a list of data. Each position in a list corresponds with the same positions in the other lists. List_1[0] has corresponding data in List_2[0] and List_3[0], etc. I would like to turn these three lists into a dictionary inside a dictionary, with the values in List_1 being the primary keys. How do I do this while keeping everything in order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> c = [7,8,9]
>>> dict(zip(a, zip(b, c)))
{1: (4, 7), 2: (5, 8), 3: (6, 9)}
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) for more info on `zip`.

As lionbest points out below, you might want to look at [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) if your input data is large. `izip` does essentially the same thing as `zip`, but it creates iterators instead of lists. This way, you don't create large temporary lists before creating the dictionary.

Comment: If a,b,c will be huge, I recommend izip from itertools module.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3:

```
combined = {name:dict(data1=List_2[i], data2=List_3[i]) for i, name in enumerate(List_1)}
```

Python 2.5:

```
combined = {}
for i, name in enumerate(List_1):
    combined[name] = dict(data1=List_2[i], data2=List_3[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

if the order of these things matters, you should not use a dictionary.  by definition, they are unordered.  you can use one of the [many ordered_dictionary implementations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/#reference-implementation) floating around, or wait for python 2.7 or 3.1 which will include an ordered dictionary implementation in the collections module.